# swap two variables without using a third variable as an intermediary position

Tags: c++

Write a program to swap two variables without using a third variable as an intermediary 
position.

```
a=2; b=3;
a=a*b; // 6
b=a/b; // 2
a=a/b; // 3
a=3 and b=2
```

????is it true,,,i have errors in it

Comment: Homework?  You can look up a solution on the web.  The classic one uses xor.

Comment: can you be a little more specific about what your question/errors are?

Comment: `std::swap`? Otherwise tag as homework.

Comment: you will have problems with 0 values

Answer (score 1):

better use reversible operators without "singularities". Such as `+`, `-` (assuming integer wraparounds are ok.

And, of course, the winner is XOR.

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if b or a is zero? If neither is zero and you do not get overflow of the type your code will work.